# PyAudio Print Sound Level From 1 To 100

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I am looking to get the sound coming from my microphone printed out as a loudness level from 1 to 100 using PyAudio. Currently my code just prints the raw sound which is just numbers and letters, how would I turn it into a scale from 1 to 100? Here is my code so far:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import threading

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNEL = 1
RATE = 44100

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pa.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNEL,
                 rate=RATE, input=True, 
                 frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)


def getdata():
    threading.Timer(1, getdata).start()
    audio_data = stream.read(CHUNK) 
    print(audio_data)


getdata()
```

I am quite a beginner so please explain thing thoroughly. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a small sample of what is outputted:

`0\xdd\x00\xdf\x00\xd6\x00\xd4\x00\xd8\x00\xc3\x00\xb6\x00\xc5\x00\xd0\x00\xc1\x00\xbb\x00\xbf\x00\xc5\x00\xc6\x00\xcf\x00\xb7\x00\xb1\x00\xcb\x00\xc2\x00\xc8\x00\xc5\x00\xc6\x00\xbe\x00\xaa\x00\xac\x00\xb1\x00\xa8\x00\xa7\x00\xb3\x00\xaa\x00\xa6\x00\xaa\x00\xa4\x00\x98\x00\x92\x00\xa0\x00\x9a\x00\x99\x00\x95\x00\x9f\x00\xb0\x00\x90\x00\x94\x00\x91\x00\x98\x00\xa2\x00\xa3\x00\xaa\x00\x94\x00\x98\x00\xa1\x00\x9d\x00\x96\x00\x90\x00\x91\x00\x89\x00\x85\x00{\x00\x83\x00\x84\x00\x8b\x00\x85\x00|\x00z\x00\x83\x00\x88\x00\x89\x00\x8a\x00\x8b\x00\x84\x00\x8f\x00\x83\x00o\x00p\x00p\x00\x88\x00\x8c\x00\x8b\x00\x8d\x00\x89\x00y\x00r\x00s\x00w\x00q\x00a\x00q\x00i\x00`

SOLVED: Found an answer here:

[Pyaudio : how to check volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868428/pyaudio-how-to-check-volume)

Comment: I am not an expert on pyaudio but, maybe the raw is a hex data? why don't convert to int? Other suggestion, I think that `threading.Timer(1, getdata).start()` will call `get_data()` recursively, do you want that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyaudio : how to check volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868428/pyaudio-how-to-check-volume)

Comment: @EmmanuelArias Without that it only does it once. I will try converting it to an integer.